# Allocate memory to double dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wanted to ask if it is possible to allocate an array in C using malloc if we know  the value of number of columns but not number of rows.

```
int Array[runtime value][N];
```

Comment: Just defer allocation until you do know the number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A few ways to do that.

Actually not a run-time, but you don't have to specify one dimension:

```
int array[][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

On stack, where `rows` is run-time a variable:

```
int array[rows][COLUMNS];
```

On heap using `malloc`, but don't forget to call `free` later:

```
int (*array)[COLUMNS];
array = malloc(rows*sizeof(int[COLUMNS]));

// ...

free(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can either allocate one dynamically:

```
// Allocate the columns
int** two_dimensional_array = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(int*));

// Find the number of rows on runtime
// however you please.

// Allocate the rest of the 2D array
int i;
for (i = 0; i < COLUMNS; ++i) {
    two_dimensional_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * ROWS);
}
```

Or, you can have one on the stack with a variable size (C99):

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);

int arr[n][COLUMNS];
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. :) I was confused if somehow we can use a static array or not.

Comment: @tariqzafar: Yes, you can use C array, `malloc` is not necessary.